# php its stuck with 0 ? fetch from db

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_select_db('moodle');
            $ht = "";
            $sql = "select * from absence where username='iset' ";
            $sql_query = mysql_query($sql);

            while( $row = mysql_fetch_object($sql_query) ){
                $ht +=  "<li>".$row->classe."</li>";

            }
echo $ht;
?>
```

always // 0 
i have 3 lines in 'absence' with username = 'iset'
i think the problem with $ht but !!!
thanks advanced

Answer (score 6):

[String concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) in PHP is done using `.` , not `+`.

This line

```
            $ht +=  "<li>".$row->classe."</li>";
```

Should become

```
            $ht .=  "<li>".$row->classe."</li>";
```

Comment: $var += $var2;  only woks for numbers addition or equals to

Comment: Exactly, that's why he was getting a zero `0`, since += produces a number.